# Objective-C Get Value From Key NSDictionary and NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary called productionSchedule, inside is 1 key/value pair and the key of that is called KeyValue, the value of the KayValue is 31 elements, inside each of those elements in a 2 key/value pair NSDictionary and there is a Key and Value. What I am trying to do is get the Value (which is an NSDictionary) of the Key for example FA50100. Here is a screenshot of productionSchedule

[image]

Here are items I have tried

```
NSDictionary *productionDictionary = [[productionSchedule valueForKey:@"KeyValue"] valueForKey:[prodSchedSortedKeys objectAtIndex:0]];
```

How would I get the Value based off a certain Key

This gives me all the values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[productionSchedule objectForKey:@"KeyValue"] valueForKey:@"Value"]);
```

I think I am just missing something inbetween KeyValue and Value

When I try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[productionSchedule objectForKey:@"KeyValue"] valueForKey:@"FA50100"] valueForKey:@"Value"]);
```

I get 31 nulls :(

Comment: What do you mean by a certain key?

Comment: I mean how would I get the @"Value" based off the @"Key"

Comment: you can do yourDict[@"yourKey"]

Comment: so `productionSchedule[@"yourKey"]`

Comment: Nope that did not work, it returns Null

Comment: You have a dictionary of an array of an dictionary (`value` is of type `NSArray`.) Therefore you need to apply an index like this: `ps[@"KeyValue"][0][@"key"]` to get `@"FA50100"`.  How did you get the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

A. Reading the dump

The dump is a little bit confusing because of LLDB. Let's have a look on it.

This is what you get:

```
productionSchedule (dictionary with 1 kvp)
  [0] @"KeyValue" : 31 elements
    key = @"KeyValue"
    value = array of 31 elements
  …
```

What? A dictionary with an *index* 0?! This is, because dictionaries are represented internally as a list of paired keys and values. Therefore this is simply the first pair of the list. Let's write it more semantically and forget the key = and value = beneath it:

```
productionSchedule (dictionary with 1 kvp)
  @"KeyValue" : array with 31 Elements
  …
```

So with

```
productionSchedule[@"KeyValue"] // evals to an array
```

you get an array with 31 elements. You have to access this array by an index. Let's say, you want go get the first element of this array. (Since you did not recognize the array at this layer, you did not say, what element you want. Maybe you want to search through the array. Let me know).

```
productionSchedule (dictionary with 1 kvp)
  @"KeyValue" : 31 elements
    [0] dictionary with 2 kvp
  …
```

The first element of this array is a dictionary.

```
productionSchedule[@"KeyValue"][0] // evals to a dictionary
```

It has two kvp. Again, forget about the indexing. It is a dictionary:

```
productionSchedule (dictionary with 1 kvp)
  @"KeyValue" : 31 elements
    [0] dictionary with 2 kvp
      @"Key" : @"FA50100"
  …
```

So to get the `@"FA50100"`, you have to do

```
productionSchedule[@"KeyValue"][0][@"Key"] // evals to a dictionary
```

B. The structure

Let me say this: The whole structure seems to be corrupted. How did you create it? Without having the full information, I would give you some advices:

a) It is completely meaningless to have a dictionary with *one* kvp and a meaningless key @"KeyValue". First we have to throw it away and start with the array.

b) Inside this array you have 31 elements. I assume that this is the real list. But this is modelled with a dictionary with 2 kvp. (I assume that this structure applies to the rest of the 31 elements, too.) The dictionary is like this

@"Key" : @"FA50100"
   @"Value" : dictionary with 6 kvp

c) So you created a kvp inside a collection that holds kvp. What is the sence of doing so!??!

Obviously `@"FA50100"` is something like an id and the value referred as `@"Value"` is the data for this key. So simply throw away the array and stor ID and its data in a single dictionary:

```
@"FA50100" : dictionary with 6 kvp.
```

Then you can access the values for `@"FA50100"` simply by

```
NSDictionary *collection = …
collection[@"FA50100"] // gets the dictionary for FA50100
```

d) If c is not possible, because the id `@"FA50100"` can occur more than one time in the list, go back using an array and put the id into the dictionary with the 6 kvp.

*But never, really never, use keys like @"Key" or @"Value" in a dictionary.*

C. For Debugging

However, here's a hint, if you get lost in recursive collections: Read it from step to step and make a log on each step to get the class.

Comment: Okay, so I am able to get the key via...`productionSchedule[@"KeyValue"][0][@"Key"]` but I don't understand how to get the data via  `NSDictionary *collection = …
collection[@"FA50100"]` I can't change my data its coming from an outside source.

Comment: If you cannot change the data structure, you get, you have two options: 1. transform the data to a more convenient structure, when you get it or 2. use `[@"KeyValue"][0][@"Key"]`. Personally I would prefer the first option.